# Closure in javascript seems not working properly

Tags: javascript

I've the following code and it is not working properly. My aim is whenever i click the 'font size' such as 12, 14 and 16, then, the font size and its color need to change accordingly and simultaneously. But, it is not working as expected, Any help?

```
<body>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <h1>some heading 1 text</h1>
    <h2>some heading 2 text</h2>

    <a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
    <a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>
    <a href="#" id="size-16">16</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function(oclor) {

    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    document.body.style.color = oclor;
  };
}
var a= "green", b= "blue", c="red";

var size12 = makeSizer(12)(a);
var size14 = makeSizer(14)(b);
var size16 = makeSizer(16)(c);

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;

</script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Your vars are not a function.

Comment: So I suppose the `sizeX` variables are all `undefined`? Your `makeSizer` returns a function, which you immediately call with arguments `a`, `b`, and `c` respectively.

Comment: You should be more precise with your problem description. "Not working as expected" doesn't really tell anybody anything. But you should start by looking at your assignments of `size12`, and the other functions, since you immediately invoke them rather than simply assigning them to the variable.

Comment: @Palpatim *"My aim is whenever i click the 'font size' such as 12, 14 and 16, then, the font size and its color need to change accordingly and simultaneously"*

Comment: @Popnoodles I understand the expected behavior. "not working as expected" doesn't say what the actual behavior is.

Comment: I see! There's one way to find out.

Comment: Why the down votes..? what is wrong with this question..? somebody was trying something, he couldn't understand why his code is not working so he seeked help... i don't understand what's the wrong part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where your problem is.

You're setting the variables to the result of the anonymous function.  Which is `undefined`.
Then you're setting the onclick events to the results.

```
var size12 = makeSizer(12)(a);
var size14 = makeSizer(14)(b);
var size16 = makeSizer(16)(c);

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;
```

What you want is to set the variables to functions as well.  Such as:

```
var size12 = function(){makeSizer(12)(a)};
```

Comment: You have to bind the click event to a function.  You're binding it to the result of a function.  Which in this case is `undefined`.  When you call `makeSizer` in the variable declarations.  You're executing the functions and storing the result in the variable.  The result is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't do the following?

Edit: Sorry, missed the return function. Thanks for pointing that out @DanielKnippers

```
function makeSizer(size,oclor) {
    return function () {
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
        document.body.style.color = oclor;
    };
}

var size12 = makeSizer(12,'green');
var size14 = makeSizer(14,'blue');
var size16 = makeSizer(16,'red');
```

Comment: This is basically what he does; it immediately executes the function and sets the variables to undefined (the result of the function).

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers i think he meant [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pSBqr/) but posted something else...

Comment: @TilwinJoy Possibly, but he did not ;) But what you made indeed *is* different, and arguably cleaner than the other answer, which wraps each variable in a function.

Comment: Sorry, I did and missed the return function. Updated the answer, thanks for pointing that out @DaniëlKnippers